# WSL2 docker-compose - unable to prepare context

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am using the Docker Engine running on WSL2 which is running on Windows 10 computer. My goal is to create a service using the Docker-compose that uses the `php:fpm` image and install the `mysqli` extension to it. Here is my `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx:
    image: "nginx"
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - '3030:80'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./config/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
        - code-network
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: php:fpm
    volumes:
        - ./src:/src
    networks:
        - code-network
  mariadb:
    image: "mariadb:10.3.24"
    restart: 'always'
    volumes:
      - "/var/lib/mysql/data:/data"
      - "/var/lib/mysql/logs:/logs"
      - /var/docker/mariadb/conf:/etc/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "T05CNCitk2020@"
      MYSQL_USER: "user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "Heslo123"
    networks:
        - code-network

networks:
    code-network:
        driver: bridge
```

And here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

When I run the command `docker-compose up --build` which forces the container to rebuild. I ran into the following problem:

```
Building php
unable to prepare context: path "\\\\?\\\\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu-20.04\\home\\vendasky\\Projects\\sql-gui" not found
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build : Build failed
```

I do not see the reason why the path should be wrong when all the files are located in the Linux subsystem. Any hints, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

are you runnning this with docker desktop for windows?

If thats the case try enabling the Docker Compose V2 option under the experimental settings. This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Docker is unable to find the path to that project, map your ubuntu correctly so it can easily locate the project, that should fix your issue.

Comment: This is not an answer but a scolding. Make sure to include the how to then do the mapping.